# Do energy Gels help in long Tennis matches

Tags: tennis

I do a lot of long distance running and I normally take a gel if I am racing and it goes longer than 2 hours. (Like a Marathon) My question is for tennis would I get the same benefit? For example, a tennis match could last 2-3 hours. Would taking a gel every 40-50 minutes help mitigate cramping and give me some energy later in the match?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it really depends on the duration of the match ; however it would definitely help and trigger your energy.
 Since you also run while playing tennis, the effects of the gel should be similar.
I would not mind using before the match .